# How to remove all of ticks keeping the extra ticks

Tags: pgfplots

I want something like

```
\begin{axis}[
  y ticks=\empty,
  extra y ticks={-1,1},
  extra y tick style={yticklabels={{name1},{name2}}
] ...
\end{axis}
```

Comment: Please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and spend some more words to describe the problem.

Comment: Actually, change "y ticks=\empty" to "ytick=\empty" and addplot a simple function, say {x}. Your code should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to have extra ticks to customize their labels. If I understand correctly you want something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ytick={1,3},
    yticklabels={name1,name2}]
\addplot+[samples=100,domain=-2:2] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]